# how to delete all data and the update the page without refreshing using useEffect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to delete all my data in API using a "delete all" button with event handler, where it calls an async function to set my `items` to an empty array. While doing that, I would like it to update my page every time I click the button and update the page data without refreshing the page using `useEffect`. However, the page updates only when I refresh the page(behave like `componentDidMount()`). After some research, I realized that adding `items` in the `useEffect` hook in the array argument would tell DOM to rerender, only when `items` is changed. However, after some debugging, I realized `handleDelete` function is called every time I refresh the page, which is something I don't want it to do. I have searched and found a lot of question regarding this issue, but no answers can solve my problem. Is there a way to get around it? I would like the page to update only when I click the delete button and no more that that.

Here is my code

```
export default function Dashboard() {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

    const fetchList = async () => {
        await axios.get("/api/items").then((res) => {
            setItems(res.data.reverse());
        });
    };

    const handleDelete = () =>{
        axios.delete("/api/items").then((res)=>{
            setItems(res.data);
            console.log('-- res.data --', res.data)
        })
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchList();
        console.log("fetchList activate")
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.dashboard_container}>
            <button className={styles.delete_all} onClick={handleDelete}>Delete All</button>
            {items.map((item) => {
                const { _id, name, phone, numberofpeople, time } = item;

                return (
                    <div className={styles.waitlist_item} key={_id}>
                        <h4>{name}</h4>
                        <h5>{phone}</h5>
                        <h4>{numberofpeople}</h4>
                        <h5>{moment(time).format("MMM Do, h:mm:ss A ddd")}</h5>
                    </div>
                );
...
```

Here is the code in my backend router that deals with delete request.

```
router.delete("/api/items", (req, res) => {
    Item.deleteMany({}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500);
        } else {
            res.json({ success: true });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You do not need to use `useEffect` here, `setItems` should do the job. Just return an empty array from back end. `res.json([])` should work.

Comment: Yes, that works too, but I would like to update my page when clicking the button. Maybe you mean ```useEffect(() => {
        fetchList();
        console.log("fetchList activate")
    }, [items]);```

Comment: What do you mean  here: "update my page"? Your page, to be precisely that part where you "visualize" items will be updated automatically without page refresh. What did I miss?

Comment: By "update my page", I mean when I click on the button, I would like to remove all my data on the page visually. Right now, the button although delete the data in the database, but it doesn't reflect on the page immediately unless I refresh the page.

Comment: ok, let's debug together) could you console.log('-- res.data --', res.data) in `handleDelete` function. And please remove second `useEffect` (where you remove items second time after items have been changed) it should not be here

Comment: ```const handleDelete = async () =>{
        await axios.delete("/api/items").then((res)=>{
            setItems(res.data);
            console.log('-- res.data --', res.data)
        })
        
    }``` you mean this right? when I l click the button, nothing happens, not even in the console, nothing is printed out in the console

Comment: correct!
btw you do not need `async` here since you are not using `await` inside the function,

Comment: so, seems like your backend does not work properly, at least here `router.delete("/", (req, res) => {` should be correct route `router.delete("/items", (req, res) => {` or maybe `router.delete("/api/items", (req, res) => {`. Not sure. Have you checked that data in DB is removed after button clicked?

Comment: You can simply check your front end side logic by this delete handler: ` const handleDelete =  () => { setItems([]) }`

Comment: I am thinking about that too, because I do get a pending response when the button is clicked, but all data are removed when the button is clicked(I have checked the DB right after I click the button) very strange.   I will do that now

Comment: But ` const handleDelete = () => { setItems([]) }` works properly?

Comment: ok, so we are making progress. ```const handleDelete = () =>{
        console.log("setItems to []")
        setItems([]);
        
    }```  I have changed my code to this, and after clicking the button, the data is removed, but if I refresh the page, it came back, meaning it is not deleted on the DB

Comment: This is expected, since we are not doing request to the server, I just wanted to verify that your front end logic working properly. I've posted some suggestions regarding backed. So once you fix your backend your logic will work properly end to end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions regarding backend:

```
router.delete("/", (req, res) => {
    Item.deleteMany({}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            response.status(500);
        } else {
            (res) => res.json({ success: true });
        }
    });
});
```

Should be `res.status(500)` instead of `response.status(500)`

Check your route, this one seems to be incorrect, try `/itmes` or maybe `/api/items`

`(res) => res.json({ success: true });` this part also seems incorrect, should be:

```
else {
   res.json({ success: true }); // or res.json([])
}
```

Good luck!)

Comment: I have changed my backend, and now it seems that I am getting status 200 response from my delete request. But I am getting an error ```TypeError: items.map is not a function```, I have attached that part of the code in my original post. I guess it is because now nothing is inside the DB, so we can't use ```map()``` on an empty ```items``` ?

Comment: Have you tried res.json([]) ? What do you see in console.log('-- res.data --', res.data)

Comment: I just did it! I tried ```setItem([])``` in my ```handleDelete()``` function, it works now. Now the ```res.data``` outputs the object ```{success: true}```. Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: so basically, after deleting all the data in DB, I am guessing ```items``` becomes a empty object, and ```map()``` only applies to array so that's why I am getting the error. If I just set ```setItem``` to an empty array, that error disappears and delete request is also successful.

Answer (score 0):

Your handleDelete in being called when the fetchList add the data into items.

You can do it like this:
Create a new state

```
const [deleteAll, setDeleteAll] = useState(false);
```

Change your button to:

```
    <button className={styles.delete_all} onClick={() => setDeleteAll(true)}>Delete All</button>
```

and change your useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        handleDelete();
        console.log("handleDelete activate")
    }, [deleteAll == true])
```

Comment: ```handleDelete``` is still called on refreshing the page, and it is called twice for some reason. fetchList gets called once and handleDelete twice in the console.

Comment: When your fetchList sets the data into items, your handleDelete is being called.

Comment: I see the problem now. so every time I refresh the page, items is changed twice so handleDelete is called twice. Do you have a way to avoid that?

Comment: I've changed the answer. You can create a state to deal only with the delete all data.

Answer (score 0):

here you can setitem value and filter by deleteone and send a id by onclick to the id can filter and render all data without render

```
    const handleDelete = (id) =>{
            axios.delete("/api/items").then((res)=>{
  setitem((prevItem) => prevItem.filter((item) => item._id !== id));
                
            })
            
        }
```